# Number of possible ways to go from point $A$ to $B$ using three types of train?

Tags: combinatorics

We have three trains to choose from.

Train $1$ - Stops at every station.

Train $2$ - Stops at every alternative station.

Train $3$ - stops at every third station.

Now we have to go from point $A$ to $B$ using any of the three trains but we cannot go backwards.

How many ways are there to go from point $A$ to $B$?

Comment: Are you asking for $6$ different answers, based on the congruency class (mod $6$) of $(B - A)$, measured in stops?  Alternatively, are you asking for a single formula that incorporates the congruency class variations?

Comment: single formula or any way in which I can count the number of ways

Comment: If the *latter* is preferred, I see no alternative to the following initial contrivance: let $$c = \left\lfloor \frac{B-A}{3}\right\rfloor,$$ where $\lfloor r\rfloor$ denotes the *floor* of $r$ (i.e. the largest integer $\leq r$).

Comment: Further clarification needed.  "Train 3 stops at every third station."  Are we to assume that if each station is assigned an index number $\{0,1,2,\cdots\},~$ that Train 3 stops (for example) at Stations $(0,3,6, \cdots)$ and that there is no Train 3 service (for example) at Stations $(1,2,4,5,\cdots)$ or are we to assume that if (for example) you board Train 3 at Station 1, its first stop will be Station 4?

Comment: I can give you only two examples because I don't have any more examples Suppose there are no stations between A and B we have to board on Train 1 only. If we have 2 stops between A and B we can board on Train1 and Train 2.

Comment: I'm not asking for you to give an example.  I am asking for you to make a **decision**, without which the problem is **ambiguous**.  Your last responding comment is confusing to me.  Please try to respond **directly** to the question that my previous comment broached.

Comment: Yes it's stop will be station 4

Comment: @user2661923 so what will be the possible solution?

Comment: See my just given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's responses to my comments:

Assume that each station is assigned an index number, and that the difference between the index numbers assigned to stations $B$ and $A$ is $n > 0.$

As suggested in one of my comments, let

$$c = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor.$$

Then, clearly, the trip will involve $a$ Train-3 trips, where

$$a \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, c\}.$$

Here, I am construing (for example) the Train-3 trip from 1 to 4 to 7 as 2 separate Train-3 trips.

For each $a \in \{0,1,2\cdots,c\}$, let

$$B_a = \left\lfloor \frac{n-3a}{2}\right\rfloor.$$

Then, for each $a$, there can be $b$ Train-2 trips, where

$$b \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, B_a\}.$$

For a given combination of $a$ Train-3 trips and $b$ Train-2 trips, there will be $(n - 3a - 2b)$ Train-1 trips, so there will be a total of 
$(n-3a-2b) + a + b  = (n-2a-b)$ trips.

These $(n-2a-b)$ trips can be **arranged** in $\binom{n-2a-b}{a} \times \binom{[n-2a-b]-a}{b}$ ways.

Let $f(a,b)$ denote $(n-2a-b).$

Then the number of possible **arrangements** of train trips is

$$\sum_{a=0}^c \sum_{b=0}^{B_a} \left[\binom{f(a,b)}{a} \times \binom{f(a,b)-a}{b}\right].$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119468/discussion-on-answer-by-user2661923-number-of-possible-ways-to-go-from-point-a).